# Which is the faster performance in javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript is 10 times faster than jquery. But if I place javascript inside jquery code would be faster way or jquery way would be faster?

For eg:

```
$(selector).filter(function(){
   return this.className == 'myclass';
});
```

---

```
$(selector).filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('class') == 'myclass'; 
});
```

I think in the first method javascript is converted to jquery and then jquery to javascript and in the second method jquery is converted to javascript so the second one is performing faster. Am I right?

Comment: use http://jsperf.com/ - by the way the second one should be `return $(this).attr('class') == 'myclass';`

Comment: Alone that the second examples contains an additional function call makes the first one technically faster.

Comment: but jquery solution is `$(selector).filter('.myclass')`

Comment: and what if the object has multiple classes set? Your JS comparison is naiive and will fail on `className='myclass otherclass'

Comment: good point. use classList features on the bareback js version for parity.

Comment: My guess is that the difference will be too small to notice. Besides, adding JS code here introduces more code to maintain. I would go with the JQuery code unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: `$(this).attr('class')` is just a **very** inefficient way of accessing `this.className`. It is two function calls in the expression, but behind the scenes there are hundreds of calls. That is always going to be slower than a simple property lookup.

Answer (score 1):

> Jquery is Javascript. A javascript library to reduce vague coding,
>   collection commonly used javascript functions which has proven to help
>   in efficient and fast coding.
>
> Javascript is the source, the actual scripts that browser responds to.

Comment: You forgot to link to the source that you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

First one is faster IMO as you are using native javascript this.className, you can check it on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/)

I have made a test to check the performance difference you can find results [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-classname)

[image: Javascript vs jQuery]

Thanks to @RevanProdigalKnight who added another performance test case [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-classname/2).

Comment: Thanks @RevanProdigalKnight, so nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is faster then jQuery, but you have to write the code in optimized way.

Comment: "always" anything is almost always wrong. If you write crappy x-browser handling, and jQuery has an optimized call, it could be faster. doubt everything until you bench real-life usage. For example, i've seen many drag and drop scripts that ask "am i in IE?" onmousemove...

Answer (score 0):

you're wrong, its all javascript, including the jQuery parts.

the thing is, pretty much anything that invokes the jQuery lib, is (relatively) slow

and your first code is faster, it only invokes jQuery once, and compares a string property with 'myclass'

your second code, invokes jQuery twice, and calls the jquery .atter function , and compares the return value of that function with 'myclass'

bored? do some benchmarks! :D